# change language from english to hindi of same activity and save as default language until it again changesthrough spinner in android?

Tags: android

How to change language from english to hindi of same activity and save as default language until it again changes the language through spinner in android?

```
spinnerLanguage.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        if (pos == 1) {

            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                 "You have selected Hindi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                 .show();
            setLocale("hi");
            spinnerLanguage.setSelection(pos);

        } else if (pos == 2) {

            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                 "You have selected English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                 .show();
            setLocale("en");
            spinnerLanguage.setSelection(pos);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String languageToLoad  = "en"; // your language 
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);  
Locale.setDefault(locale); 
Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
config.locale = locale; 
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,  
getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

then you should save the language like this

```
SharedPreferences languagepref = getSharedPreferences("language",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = languagepref.edit();
editor.putString("languageToLoad",languageToLoad );
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon changing language, save your local code in `sharedPreferences`, and on `onStart()` set locale.